# Is there a possibility to get multiple lists from a hibernate native sql query?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I need in a single database hit, 2 lists first matching some condition and the second is a NOT IN the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
List<Object[]> results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(*), type from Record group by 2").list();
```

and then process the result list to your data structure.